# Material Ui responsive

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I am working on creating  a web application using react js and material ui, 
but I am not getting responsiveness in the app. 
This is the code in my head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Roboto"  rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

Comment: and where is material-ui-css in this code ?

Comment: can you please mention the line which I am missing @Amir-Mousavi

Comment: What kind of problem with responsiveness are you having? Please show the code of the part that isn't behaving as you would expect and describe what the current behavior is compared to the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `npm` for installing the material-ui there is no need for hardcoding any scripts or CSS link at the index file. the installed module via npm will handle all injections.

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

if you are insisting to not use the npm , include the following at the index `head` tag

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
```

a very simple [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7q62w83q8) which copy-pasted form material-ui examples shows that it works correctly and fully responsive,

in that sample, you can see that the Grids are responsive and get stacked at reducing the page size.

Comment: Actually I have installed  material-UI using npm, can you tell what can be other possible  reason for this

Comment: if you can re/produce your problem, sure I can take a look. but by just seeing the index file here nothing is clear what the reason can be